# How to load js file at the beginning of the head in vuepress2

Tags: vuepress2

I use vuepress2 and want to import a js file.
It will append to the end of the head when I append config in the .vuepress/config.ts

```json
 head: [
    ['script', { type: 'text/javascript', src: '*.js' }]
  ]
```

How can I append the js to the beginning of the head.